# How find out Query or Mutation return type in ExceptionFilter [NestJS]

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I have a problem with union types combined with ValidationPipe and ExceptionFilter. Basically what I want to achieve is to somehow know inside Filter is Query or Mutation return type is iterable or not. I have union type which looks like this:

```
const UserResponse = createUnionType({
  name: "UserResponse",
  types: () => [UserEntity, InputValidationError],
});
```

Exception filter:

```
@Catch(InputValidationError)
export class InputValidationErrorFilter implements GqlExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: InputValidationError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const gqlHost = GqlArgumentsHost.create(host);
    return exception;
  }
}
```

And some Queries and Mutations

```
 @Query(() => UserEntity)
 @UseFilters(InputValidationErrorFilter)
 user(@Args("id") id: number) {
 ...

 @Query(() => [UserResponse])
 @UseFilters(InputValidationErrorFilter)
 users() {
 ...
```

So as you could already tell I want not just throw Errors but return them as excepted results and the problem is that I can't know if exception should be iterable or not inside *InputValidationErrorFilter*. Right now throwing *InputValidationErrorFilter* inside *user* query is ok, but doing that inside *users* query is not working just because return type of error should be iterable. Maybe anybody knows how I can get return type inside Filter?

Comment: using error union types are out of graphql specs and not supported by graphql clients

Comment: Yes, but filter just catches that error and returns it as expected value. That errors doesn't go to errors array

Comment: [it should to be graphql specs compliant] .... and becomes unusable ... I guess you don't care because it (FE) is not your work